# How to get from Maastricht to Eindhoven airport 5:30 am?

Tags: airport-transfer, netherlands, ein, maastricht

I have an early flight from Eindhoven airport. I first thought of going there with the last train but apparently the airport closes around 11 pm.

Is there another way of getting to the airport that early from Maastricht?

Trains are not an option since the first train arrives to Eindhoven at 6:30 am, and it takes another 30 min to get from the city to the airport by bus.

Answer (score 6):

This in not the "ultimate answer" since it may not fit everyone, but it may help some of you. A possibility is renting a car in the city of departure and leaving it in Eindhoven Airport. It's possible to leave it at any hour. You can drop the keys in a special box inside the airport (Go straight to the airport after leaving the car. Don't leave the keys in the mailbox near the renting agencies. The drop-off point for the keys is inside the main hall of the airport)

It may seem expensive for some intially but it will probably be cheaper than sleeping over in Eindhoven  and it may be approximately as expensive as the train trip (depending on how many people are travelling).

It's worth checking!

Note: the nearest gas pump (that I know of) to the airport is around 6Km away. Don't forget to fill the tank before arriving to the airport or you may have to go back.

Comment: @pnuts if it may help, why not? It was a good solution to me.

Comment: @pnuts I may be mistaken but stack exchange is not only about canonical answers. Sometimes there are many ways of solving a problem depending on your circunstances. I just highlighted one that may actual be superior to others due to some local circunstance that I explained.

Answer (score 5):

**No.** The quite complete [online travel planner](http://9292.nl/) offers no solution of getting there so early. You will need to travel the evening before and spend the night in Eindhoven, then travel from Eindhoven to Eindhoven Airport in the morning. The first bus from the city centre appears to depart at 5:43 (bus 401), so you will need to take a taxi.

Comment: There's a hotel fairly close to the airport though, next to the highway (10 minute walk; 5 minute from bus stop "Flight Forum").

Comment: Right, I didn't check for that.

Comment: If you really need to be in Maastricht your last night, you can organize a taxi transfer to the airport, but remember that you will need more time than just travel time for the distance, making it a very short night.